# Right syntax to use near

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run this script, but I have this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(than appear 3 users)' at 
line 1

Code:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect('localhost','root,'','dbtest')          
cursor = conn.cursor()

add_data = ("""INSERT INTO data VALUES %s,%s,%s""" %(user, twet, time))
cursor.execute(add_data)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

I belive that the error is in the %s,%s,%s, I tried a lot of diferent formats but it's always the same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for your connection to your database should read in the lines of:

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect('localhost','root','','dbtest')
```

And maybe change your insert statement to:

```
add_data = ("INSERT INTO data VALUES (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")" % (user, twet, time))
```

Comment: This is incorrect, and it does not address the string substitution that is inappropriate here.

Comment: The syntax of connection was my mistake copying to here. And I tried this insert and gives the same error, but tuis time instead of giving me 3 user is 3 tweets..

Comment: 3 - user, tweet, time

Comment: I did edit my solution. I also made a typo copying... :D

Comment: I don't know. Maybe try putting the table name in single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You must never ever use string substitution in SQL queries. Use the db-api's parameter substitution. Apart from anything else, it will solve one of your syntax problems, which is that your strings are not quoted; it will do that automatically.

The other syntax issue you have, as Mario pointed out, is that arguments to VALUES need to be in parentheses. So, putting those together:

```
add_data = """INSERT INTO data VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
cursor.execute(add_data, (user, twet, time))
```

Comment: Now I have this - Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'series' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Comment: I'm new in Python and Mysql, can you explain how to use db-api's parameter substitution? or give a link with good info

Comment: You use it like I showed you. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you said.. but I have this error: Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'series' cannot be converted to a MySQL type.

Comment: So, one of your params - user, twet, or time - appears to be of a type called "series" which MySQL doesn't know what to do with. You'll need to give more information about what they are.

Comment: In user I have something like this "Luu\u2764", in tweet "Que mala suerte loco \ud83d\ude1e\ud83d\ude22\ud83d\ude22" and in time "Wed Apr 01 12:56:01 +0000 2015", I think the problem is in time. Have a not good format.... User e tweet - varchar, time - datetime. need more info?

Comment: Made a change in time and user (now is showing right), so maybe the problem is the tweet. But I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Now I have this:  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 483, in execute
    stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax should be with parenthesis:

`INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country) VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');`

Comment: I think that your answer is not for Python. Anyway this don't work. Thanks

Comment: Your `add_data = ("""INSERT INTO data VALUES %s,%s,%s"""...` should be `add_data = ("""INSERT INTO data VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""...`